# How to fix Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I solve this problem? 
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.lblNamnEfternamn.text = personsArray[indexPath.row].wholeName
    cell.lblEmail.text = personsArray[indexPath.row].email
    cell.imageAvatar.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")

    if let newProfileImageUrl = personsArray[indexPath.row].profileImageUrl {
        let url = NSURL(string: newProfileImageUrl)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageAvatar.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: in your current approach , you may also need `task.resume()`

Comment: you can only use if let to unwrap an optional. The error says profileImageUrl is not an optional. So you don't have to use if let.

Comment: You could declare profileImageUrl to be String? instead of String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
if let newProfileImageUrl = personsArray[indexPath.row].profileImageUrl {
```

with

```
let newProfileImageUrl = personsArray[indexPath.row].profileImageUrl
```

Also it's better to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

```
cell.imageAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:newProfileImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

instead of repeatedly fetching the image every scroll

Comment: doesn't help more errors show up

Comment: remove the closing `}` of the `if let`